# PHP Nested JSON from flat JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a database query that provides me the output of some employee data. I want to use this data to pass to a plugin that generates an org chart. There are a few fields in the JSON object that I am pulling down which are:

```
FirstName
LastName
EmployeeID
ManagerEmployeeID
Manager Name
```

The data is returned as flat JSON object with no nesting or corellation between employees and their managers in the hierarchy.

Since I am unable to change the output of the source data (the database query), I am trying to figure out a way to nest the data so that the JSON output becomes a nested output.

My goal is to take this array and nest it based on the ManagerID and EmployeeID so I can make a tree hierarchy.

**Example Data:**

```
•   Tom Jones
   o    Alice Wong
   o    Tommy J.
•   Billy Bob
   o    Rik A.
     ♣  Bob Small
     ♣  Small Jones
   o    Eric C.
```

**My flat data example:**

```
    {
        "FirstName": "Tom"
        "LastName": "Jones"
        "EmployeeID": "123"
        "ManagerEmployeeID": ""
        "Manager Name": ""
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Alice"
        "LastName": "Wong"
        "EmployeeID": "456"
        "ManagerEmployeeID": "123"
        "Manager Name": "Tom Jones"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Tommy"
        "LastName": "J."
        "EmployeeID": "654"
        "ManagerEmployeeID": "123"
        "Manager Name": "Tom Jones"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Billy"
        "LastName": "Bob"
        "EmployeeID": "777"
        "ManagerEmployeeID": ""
        "Manager Name": ""
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Rik"
        "LastName": "A."
        "EmployeeID": "622"
        "ManagerEmployeeID": "777"
        "Manager Name": "Billy Bob"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Bob"
        "LastName": "Small"
        "EmployeeID": "111"
        "ManagerEmployeeID": "622"
        "Manager Name": "Rik A."
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Small"
        "LastName": "Jones"
        "EmployeeID": "098"
        "ManagerEmployeeID": "622"
        "Manager Name": "Rik A"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Eric"
        "LastName": "C."
        "EmployeeID": "222"
        "ManagerEmployeeID": "777"
        "Manager Name": "Billy Bob"
    }
```

**Example Desired Output:**

```
[
  {
    "FirstName": "Tom",
    "LastName": "Jones",
    "EmployeeID": "123",
    "ManagerEmployeeID": "",
    "Manager Name": "",
    "employees": [
      {
        "FirstName": "Alice",
        "LastName": "Wong",
        "EmployeeID": "456",
        "ManagerEmployeeID": "123",
        "Manager Name": "Tom Jones"
      },
      {
        "FirstName": "Tommy",
        "LastName": "J.",
        "EmployeeID": "654",
        "ManagerEmployeeID": "123",
        "Manager Name": "Tom Jones"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Billy",
    "LastName": "Bob",
    "EmployeeID": "777",
    "ManagerEmployeeID": "",
    "Manager Name": "",
    "employees": [
      {
        "FirstName": "Rik",
        "LastName": "A.",
        "EmployeeID": "622",
        "ManagerEmployeeID": "777",
        "Manager Name": "Billy Bob",
        "employees": [
          {
            "FirstName": "Bob",
            "LastName": "Small",
            "EmployeeID": "111",
            "ManagerEmployeeID": "622",
            "Manager Name": "Rik A."
          },
          {
            "FirstName": "Small",
            "LastName": "Jones",
            "EmployeeID": "098",
            "ManagerEmployeeID": "622",
            "Manager Name": "Rik A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "FirstName": "Eric",
        "LastName": "C.",
        "EmployeeID": "222",
        "ManagerEmployeeID": "777",
        "Manager Name": "Billy Bob"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Esentially I am trying to create a nested JSON output from a flat object using the `EmployeeID` and `ManagerEmployeeID` as the links between the two.

What is the best way to solve something like this with PHP?

**Bounty Update:**

Here is a test case of the issue: https://eval.in/private/4b0635c6e7b059

You will see that the very last record with the name of `Issue Here` does not show up in the result set. This has a `managerID` that matches the root node and should be within "Tom Jones's" `employees` array.

Comment: The best way - Is to write some code - test it -fix any mistakes - test it... repeat until happy with the result

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Thanks, I did that and have it working perfectly with Javascript. PHP isn't my strong suit so I am trying to figure out if there are any common functions between PHP and JS that can accomplish this. Does php have a reduce method like JS that can do this? https://jsfiddle.net/87ztvk8m/

Comment: php has `array_reduce` function. have a look at here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the following utility class to do exactly what you need.

```
class NestingUtil
{
    /**
     * Nesting an array of records using a parent and id property to match and create a valid Tree
     *
     * Convert this:
     * [
     *   'id' => 1,
     *   'parent'=> null
     * ],
     * [
     *   'id' => 2,
     *   'parent'=> 1
     * ]
     *
     * Into this:
     * [
     *   'id' => 1,
     *   'parent'=> null
     *   'children' => [
     *     'id' => 2
     *     'parent' => 1,
     *     'children' => []
     *    ]
     * ]
     *
     * @param array  $records      array of records to apply the nesting
     * @param string $recordPropId property to read the current record_id, e.g. 'id'
     * @param string $parentPropId property to read the related parent_id, e.g. 'parent_id'
     * @param string $childWrapper name of the property to place children, e.g. 'children'
     * @param string $parentId     optional filter to filter by parent
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function nest(&$records, $recordPropId = 'id', $parentPropId = 'parent_id', $childWrapper = 'children', $parentId = null)
    {
        $nestedRecords = [];
        foreach ($records as $index => $children) {
            if (isset($children[$parentPropId]) && $children[$parentPropId] == $parentId) {
                unset($records[$index]);
                $children[$childWrapper] = self::nest($records, $recordPropId, $parentPropId, $childWrapper, $children[$recordPropId]);
                $nestedRecords[] = $children;
            }
        }

        return $nestedRecords;
    }
}
```

Usage with your code:

```
$employees = json_decode($flat_employees_json, true);
$managers = NestingUtil::nest($employees, 'EmployeeID', 'ManagerEmployeeID', 'employees');
print_r(json_encode($managers));
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "FirstName": "Tom",
    "LastName": "Jones",
    "EmployeeID": "123",
    "ManagerEmployeeID": "",
    "Manager Name": "",
    "employees": [
      {
        "FirstName": "Alice",
        "LastName": "Wong",
        "EmployeeID": "456",
        "ManagerEmployeeID": "123",
        "Manager Name": "Tom Jones",
        "employees": []
      },
      {
        "FirstName": "Tommy",
        "LastName": "J.",
        "EmployeeID": "654",
        "ManagerEmployeeID": "123",
        "Manager Name": "Tom Jones",
        "employees": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Billy",
    "LastName": "Bob",
    "EmployeeID": "777",
    "ManagerEmployeeID": "",
    "Manager Name": "",
    "employees": [
      {
        "FirstName": "Rik",
        "LastName": "A.",
        "EmployeeID": "622",
        "ManagerEmployeeID": "777",
        "Manager Name": "Billy Bob",
        "employees": [
          {
            "FirstName": "Bob",
            "LastName": "Small",
            "EmployeeID": "111",
            "ManagerEmployeeID": "622",
            "Manager Name": "Rik A.",
            "employees": []
          },
          {
            "FirstName": "Small",
            "LastName": "Jones",
            "EmployeeID": "098",
            "ManagerEmployeeID": "622",
            "Manager Name": "Rik A",
            "employees": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "FirstName": "Eric",
        "LastName": "C.",
        "EmployeeID": "222",
        "ManagerEmployeeID": "777",
        "Manager Name": "Billy Bob",
        "employees": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

> Edit1 : Fix to avoid ignoring some employees
>
> **If the last item is a employee with valid manager but the manager is not in the list, then is ignored, because where should be located?, it's not a root but does not have a valid manager.**

To avoid this add the following lines just before the return statement in the utility.

```
if (!$parentId) {
    //merge residual records with the nested array
    $nestedRecords = array_merge($nestedRecords, $records);
}

return $nestedRecords;
```

> Edit2: Updating the utility to PHP5.6

After some tests in PHP7 the utility works fine in php7.0 but not in php5.6, I'm not sure why, but is something in the array reference and the unset. I update the utility code to work with php5.6 and your use case.

```
 public static function nest($records, $recordPropId = 'id', $parentPropId = 'parent_id', $childWrapper = 'children', $parentId = null)
    {
        $nestedRecords = [];
        foreach ($records as $index => $children) {
            if (isset($children[$parentPropId]) && $children[$parentPropId] == $parentId) {
                $children[$childWrapper] = self::nest($records, $recordPropId, $parentPropId, $childWrapper, $children[$recordPropId]);
                $nestedRecords[] = $children;
            }
        }

        if (!$parentId) {
            $employeesIds = array_column($records, $recordPropId);
            $managers = array_column($records, $parentPropId);
            $missingManagerIds = array_filter(array_diff($managers, $employeesIds));
            foreach ($records as $record) {
                if (in_array($record[$parentPropId], $missingManagerIds)) {
                    $nestedRecords[] = $record;
                }
            }
        }

        return $nestedRecords;
    }
```

Comment: Amazing, I will test this shortly but it looks great!

Comment: So I am trying to integrate this into my application and I am running into a little trouble. Here is a snippet of my code that I am working with. 
https://pastebin.com/j25bN7PN

Comment: can share your json in `$orgData` to make a test locally

Comment: I think I have figured it out. The only problem I am running into now is that the plugin doesn't like the square brackets on the JSON output in the beginning and the end. Is there a way in the function to tweak this so it begins and ends with { } not [{ }]

Comment: if remove `[]` then it's not a valid json, but can do this using `preg_replace('/^\[|\]$/','',json_encode($array));`

Comment: In the other hand always can use `json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)` to get a object with {}

Comment: While this is working perfectly, I noticed one small issue today. Can you think of any reason it would be omitting the last item in the array? I see the person when I print_r($employees) as the last item in the array but they are then gone once it runs through the utility. The last item in this array has a valid managerID and would be on the same level as "Tom Jones" in the original example.

Comment: What is happening is as follows, in the first iteration the utility try to find all employees when the manager is null **(see the last parameter: $parentId = null)** then recursively find employees for each manager. If the last item is a employee with valid manager but the manager is not in the list, then is ignored, because where should be located?, it's not a root but does not have a valid manager.

Comment: Can we pass the root manager's ID to the utility and start from that instead of NULL, would that then solve the problem?

Comment: If pass the manager id instead of null then all roots (manager= null) will be ignored, in the other hand the manager is ignored because the function return only employees under the given manager id. A solution can be set to null the manager id of all employees where the manager is not in the list, otherwise you need modify the utility to do that you need.

Comment: Thanks, I would prefer to not have to have other employees with NULLS for their manager ID's. I will have to take al ook at the utility and see if i can hack it up to get that part working.

Comment: I tried a few things such as `if (!$parentId) { $nestedRecords = array_merge($nestedRecords[0]['children'], $records); } ` but haven't been able to get it quite yet. My attempt was to add the remaining records to the children of the manager which I would think would be `[0]` in this scenario. It seems like `$records` is an array of arrays though so its not properly formatting the output. I may be way off but I have been attempting some solutions.

Comment: Updated OP with bounty and added a test case example.

Comment: Do you have a workaround for the issue mentioned? Your answer so far has been the only one that has worked, aside from the managers that come at the end like you had identified in your comments above.

Comment: see the latest update **Updating the utility to PHP5.6** I hope you solve with that :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct translation to PHP from your fiddle:

```
function makeTree($data, $parentId){
    return array_reduce($data,function($r,$e)use($data,$parentId){
        if(((empty($e->ManagerEmployeeID)||($e->ManagerEmployeeID==(object)[])) && empty($parentId)) or ($e->ManagerEmployeeID == $parentId)){
            $employees = makeTree($data, $e->EmployeeID);
            if($employees) $e->employees = $employees;
            $r[] = $e;
        }
        return $r;
    },[]);
}
```

It works correctly with your test input.
See https://eval.in/private/ee9390e5e8ca95.

Example usage:

```
$nested = makeTree(json_decode($json), '');
echo json_encode($nested, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

@rafrsr solution is nicely flexible, but the problem is the `unset()` inside the `foreach`.
It modifies the array while it is being iterated, which is a bad idea.
If you remove the `unset()`, it works correctly.

Comment: Trying to implement this now with my application. One thing I noticed is that when I provide a null/empty manager in my database, its treating it as  an array when I view the decoded json. `[MgrQID] => Array()`. I am having some trouble getting your code to run with my database dataset which should be just about identical. Could the above be the issue? Is it expecting to see an `array` on that value?

Comment: Can you show me the specific part of your code that you're having trouble with?

Comment: I had to give my root manager something for its managerID so I defined it as `root`. I then used your code and instead of leaving the parentID blank, I changed it to root. `$managers = makeTree($employees['data'], 'root');`. I am just getting back and empty array instead of it being formatted, trying to figure out where it went wrong.

Comment: Here is the issue - my `ManagerID` is being treated as an array since it has no value. This is causing the reduce function to fail I believe. Look at the root node, instead of being an empty string, it is actually an empty array value. https://eval.in/private/faade9774c7482 - I think accounting for that will solve the issue.

Comment: I updated the code to account for empty `ManagerEmployeeID`. Give it a try.

Comment: Same issue, empty array :/ - https://eval.in/private/b53f02c9987143 <- this is using your updated code.

Comment: My server is throwing an error and I may have been able to replicate it here. My `json` data has a root tag called `data`. I decoded it before passing it to the `makeTree` function and its throwing a memory error. Did I do something wrong? https://eval.in/private/3072c48308c2ad

Comment: @SBB Yes, you are confusing array with object. See https://eval.in/private/4125a62c7d2b40

Comment: Thanks Rei - I have tried this numerous times and for some reason, I still cant get it integrated into my code without the server timing out. I put in a simple echo within the `IF` statement in the function and it keeps printing out the same variable of the first array item multiples times (over the browsers limit) which causes it to lock up and probably cause the server to timeout as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the magic power of recursion here. Please refer below example.
**getTreeData** is being called under itself as you can see here.

```
function getTreeData($data=[], $parent_key='', $self_key='', $key='')
{
    if(!empty($data))
    {

        $new_array = array_filter($data, function($item) use($parent_key, $key) {

            return $item[$parent_key] == $key;
        });

        foreach($new_array as &$array)
        {
            $array["employees"] = getTreeData($data, $parent_key, $self_key, $array[$self_key]);

            if(empty($array["employees"]))
            {
                unset($array["employees"]);
            }
        }

        return $new_array;
    }
    else
    {
        return $data;
    }
}

$employees = json_decode($employees_json_string, true);

$employees_tree = getTreeData($employees, "ManagerEmployeeID", "EmployeeID");
```

Comment: I am getting this error: "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array " on this line: `return $item[$parent_key] == $key;`

Comment: Add true as second parameter in json_decode will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat trick that leverages the fact that objects are passed around by reference.

[`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) is first used to rekey the input array by `EmployeeID`.
[`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is then used to iterate the entries and to reassign each item to an `employees` array of the corresponding manager. Because entries are objects *(stdClass)*, the same input items are being modified.

Items that are added to `employees` array by reference, are nulled at root level. [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is then used to remove these null entries. Finally the temporary EmployeeID keying is removed by [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
$input = json_decode($flat_employees_json, true);
$input = array_column($input, null, "EmployeeID");
$input = array_map(function ($entry) {
    return (object) $entry;
}, $input);
$output = array_values(array_filter(array_map(function ($entry) use ($input) {
    if (!empty($entry->ManagerEmployeeID)) {
        $input[$entry->ManagerEmployeeID]->employees[] = $entry;
        return null;
    }
    return $entry;
}, $input)));
echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Try it [online](https://3v4l.org/Pb1aT).

PHP 7 supports an array of objects for `array_column`, so input initialization can be reduced to:

```
$input = array_column(json_decode($flat_employees_json), null, "EmployeeID");
```